# Elastic class not found in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, elasticsearch

I am having trouble installing elastic search in Laravel project. I get error

> Class 'Elastica\Client' not found

And when I try to import class with visual studio option I get no class found notification. I installed elasticsearch through composer by adding in `composer.json` file elasticsearch and then I entered `composer update`, then I added classed in `app/config.php` file and run `composer dump-autoload`. And when I enter on my site on test page I get that error. Also to mention that I use latest version of `laravel`, `php` and `mysql`. Any help is appreciated. Here is my code.

`CategoryController.php`

```
<?php
namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\User;
use App\Category;
use App\Property;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Elasticsearch\ClientBuilder;
use Elastica\Client as ElasticaClient;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Cookie;

class CategoryController extends Controller
{
    protected $elasticSearch;
    protected $elastica;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->elasticSearch = ClientBuilder::create()->build();

        $elasticaConfig = [
            'host' => 'localhost',
            'port' => 9200,
            'index' => 'pets'
        ];

        $this->elastica = new ElasticaClient($elasticaConfig);
        // Here is error!!!
    }

    public function elasticSearchTest()
    {
        dump($this->elasticSearch);
        echo "\n\nRetrieve a document:\n";
        $params = [
            'index' => 'real-estate-laravel',
            'type' => 'properties',
            'id' => '1'
        ];

        $response = $this->elasticSearch->get($params);
        dump($response);
    }
}
```

`app/config.php`

```
'providers' => [
    Elasticquent\ElasticquentServiceProvider::class,
],

'aliases' => [
    'Es' => Elasticquent\ElasticquentElasticsearchFacade::class,
],
```

`composer.json`

```
"require": {
    "php": "^7.1.3",
    "doctrine/dbal": "^2.9",
    "fideloper/proxy": "^4.0",
    "jorenvanhocht/laravel-share": "^2.0",
    "laravel/framework": "5.8.*",
    "laravel/socialite": "^4.1",
    "laravel/tinker": "^1.0",
    "mews/captcha": "^2.2",
    "predis/predis": "^1.1",
    "zizaco/entrust": "5.2.x-dev",
    "elasticquent/elasticquent": "dev-master"
},
```

web.php

```
Route::prefix('elasticsearch')->group(function () {
    Route::get('/', 'CategoryController@index')->name('startpage');

    Route::get('/search', 'CategoryController@search')->name('search.param');

    Route::get('test', ['uses' => 'CategoryController@elasticSearchTest']);
});
```

Comment: try `composer install` instead of `composer update`, because `composer update` updates the newer versions of the dependencies of the whole application.

Comment: @techguru Just did that. Same error

Comment: navigate to your vendor path and check if the package exists or not

Comment: @AshrafHefny They exist

Comment: what version of elastic are you using?

Comment: @AshrafHefny How to check that?

Comment: it depends on the  OS you're using, but you can simply send curl -XGET 'localhost:9200' and elastic will return it's version

Comment: @AshrafHefny I use windows 10 OS. Also when I localhost:9200 I get that version is 7.3.0